# window.history.events

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Я хочу перехватывать события (назад,вперед), и выполнять свою функцию.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
   alert(e.state);
}, false);
```

Вот этот код работает только с анкорами на одной странице, как при клике на якорь вылазит `alert()`, так и на кнопки "назад" и "вперед". Когда я перехожу на другую страницу, и нажимаю "назад", ничего не происходит, просто идет возврат назад, никакого алерт.

Как запретить добавление в историю якоря?
Как перехватывать историю между страницами? Как получить *url* страницы к запрашивающему *history*?

Comment: `window.onhashchange = function() {
 alert("ИЗМЕНИЛСЯ HASH СТРАНИЦЫ. URL: "+document.location.href);
}` - отследить изменение hash.